# How do I fit a 2 bit subtractor into its expression?

Tags: adder

Regular `Full subtractor` has the following:

- x,y as the inputs
- Bin - as the borrow in
- Bout - as the borrow out. *Bout expression*: x'y + x'Bin + yBin
- D - difference between x and y. (i.e x-y). *D expression*: x XOR y XOR Bin

What are the Difference and BorrowOut expressions, in case of a 2 bit Full subtractor like described in the image below? (i.e x1x0 - y1y0.. x1x0 is a two bit binary number)
[image]

Comment: What is a substructor?

Comment: @LeonHeller: Its a subtractor mixed with a terrible late night misspell :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean "subtractor".

You can think of a 2 bit subtractor as two connected 1 bit subtractors.

So, if for a 1 bit subtractor the expressions are:

- Difference = x XOR y XOR Bin
- BorrowOut = x'y + x'Bin + yBin

Then for a two bit subtractor the expressions would be:

- D0 = x0 XOR y0 XOR Bin
- Btmp = x'y + x'Bin + yBin
- D1 = x1 XOR y1 XOR Btmp
- BorrowOut = x'y + x'Btmp + yBtmp

Btmp is just used internally.

Comment: Thanks mate! I've edited the question and corrected my mistake as well.